# Changing the name of a column to date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have column names as month (string) and i need to change the names to date format

**My data:**

PC GEO Jan Feb Mar 

 A Ind 1 1 1

**Expected output**
PC GEO 2019-01-01 2019-02-01  2019-03-01

 A Ind 1 1 1

Comment: What code are you trying to execute and what is the problem with the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.set_index(['PC','GEO'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns + '2019', format='%b%Y')
print (df)
        2019-01-01  2019-02-01  2019-03-01
PC GEO                                    
A  Ind           1           1           1
```

Then you can reshape by `stack`:

```
df = df.rename_axis('date', axis=1).stack().reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
  PC  GEO       date  val
0  A  Ind 2019-01-01    1
1  A  Ind 2019-02-01    1
2  A  Ind 2019-03-01    1
```

Comment: @jezrael..bro is it possible to change the column names without indexing 'PC'& 'Geo'...because i need to **melt** the table

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - added soluton for `melt` alternative